# Jmeter is giving response as 400, when posting request with data

Tags: jmeter

it is sending post data as

`$__eval($__{FileToString("json file path ",,)})`

With no cookies

Response code 400

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer? if one is ok can you accept it so that it’s useful to others ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use Menu option :

- Tools > Function Helper Dialog

to fix your syntax as it is incorrect it should look like:

```
 ${__eval(${__FileToString(json file path,,)})}
```

Add a view result tree and check the request tab yo see if you are sending correctly data.

If yes, then check you are sending correct Content-Type header by adding a Header Manager and adding header:

```
 Content-Type : application/javascript
```

if it’s JSON or another value

Answer (score 0):

1. Your syntax is not very correct, [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) functions combination should look like:

   ```
   ${__eval(${__FileToString(json file path,,)})}
   ```

   See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) article for more details
2. You might also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and configure it to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)